# Replacing doubled letter with that letter plus a code

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to replace the second occurrence of a letter in a double letter pair with a specified code. For example, if the code is a capital letter `"X"`, then the input

```
"hello, this is silly"
```

would become

```
"helXo, this is silXy."
```

I can replace the entire pair with something like

```
StringReplace["hello, this is silly", x_ ~~ x_ -> "X"]
```

but how do I replace only the second member of the pair?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
StringReplace["hello, this is silly", x_ ~~ x_ -> x ~~ "X"]
```

> `"helXo, this is silXy"`

Answer (score 2):

```
StringReplace["hello, this is silly", x_ ~~ x_ :> x <> "X"]
```

> "helXo, this is silXy"

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex version:

```
StringReplace["hello, this is silly", RegularExpression["(\\w)\\1"] -> "$1X"]
   "helXo, this is silXy"
```